# Play multiple music files in sequence located in a Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, audio-player

Right now, we have music CDs saved in our Google Drive, so multiple classrooms can access them. However, the first song will play and not continue to the second, the third, etc. Is there a work around to this? Or is there a way to use Apps Script to tell it to play all the songs in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is a webapp that I use to listen to my music every morning.  The only caveat is that you have to return to this page if you move away from it before one of the selections stop otherwise it will not continue playing all of the selections unless the webapp is the currently selected page. It's a javascript focus issue.  I just live with it.

The script creates a playlist on a spreadsheet that allows you to select the music that you currently wish to listen to with a column of check boxes.

You will need to fiddle with this a little because I wrote it for me so it probably has some default setups that are unique to me.

html: music1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Music</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
      label{margin:2px 10px;}
    </style>
    <script>
    var selectionList=["BarbaraAnn.mp3","Don't Let Me Come Home a Stranger.mp3"];
    var gVolume=0.2;
    var index=0;
    $(function(){
       document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML="Loading Playlist";
       google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(function(Obj){
         selectionList=Obj.playlist;
         console.log(Obj.playlist);
         document.getElementById('list').innerHTML=Obj.html;
         google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(function(fObj){
           $('#audio1').attr('src',fObj.uri);
           var audio=document.getElementById("audio1");
           audio.volume=gVolume;
           audio.onended=function() {
             document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Ended...';
             playnext();
             console.log("audio onended function = playNext()");
           }
           var msg=document.getElementById('msg');
           msg.innerHTML="Click play to begin playlist. Additional selections will begin automatically";        
           audio.onplay=function() {
             document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Playing: ' + selectionList[index-1];
             document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Playing...';
             document.getElementById('skipbtn').disabled=false;
             document.getElementById("tbl1").rows[index - 1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
             document.getElementById('tbl1').rows[index].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
           }
           audio.onvolumechange=function(){
             gVolume=audio.volume;
           }         
         })
         .convMediaToDataUri(selectionList[index++]);
       })
       .getPlaylist();
    });
    function playnext() {
      if(index<selectionList.length) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Loading...';
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Next Selection: ' + selectionList[index];
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(fObj){
          $('#audio1').attr('src',fObj.uri);
          var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');
          //audio.onended = '';
          audio.volume=gVolume;
          audio.play();
          console.log(`execute playnext() index = ${index}` )
        })
        .convMediaToDataUri(selectionList[index++]);
      }else{
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML='Playlist Complete';
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('cntrls').innerHTML='<input type="button" value="Replay Playlist" onClick="replayPlaylist()" />';
      }
    }
   function replayPlaylist() {
     index=0;
     document.getElementById('cntrls').innerHTML='';
     playnext();
   }
   function skip() {
     var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');
     document.getElementById('skipbtn').disabled=true;
     audio.pause();
     playnext();
   }
   function playThis(idx) {
     index=idx;
     var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');
     //audio.pause();
     playnext();
   }
   console.log("Code");
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <audio controls id="audio1" src=""></audio><br />
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div><input type="button" id="skipbtn" value="Skip" onClick="skip()" disabled /></div>
    <div id="cntrls"></div>
    <div id="list"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Music')
  .addItem('Launch Music', 'launchMusicDialog')
  .addItem('Create New Music List', 'createMusicList')
  .addToUi();
}

function convMediaToDataUri(filename){
  var filename=filename || "You Make Loving Fun.mp3";
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  var files=folder.getFilesByName(filename);
  var n=0;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    n++;
  }
  if(n==1) {
    var blob=file.getBlob();
    var b64DataUri='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
    Logger.log(b64DataUri)
    var fObj={filename:file.getName(),uri:b64DataUri}
    return fObj;
  }
  throw("Multiple Files with same name.");
  return null;
}


function launchMusicDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('music1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Music');
}


function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('music1').addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}

function createMusicList() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("MusicList");
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  var files=folder.getFiles();
  var mA=[['Item','File Name','File Type','File Id','Play List']];
  sh.clearContents()
  var n=1;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    mA.push([n++,file.getName(),file.getMimeType(),file.getId(),'']);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,mA.length,mA[0].length).setValues(mA);
  sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()-1).sort({column:2,ascending:true});
  sh.getRange(2,5,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).insertCheckboxes();
}

function getPlaylist() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('MusicList');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var pl=[];
  var idx=0;
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Index</th><th>Item</th><th>FileName</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][4]) {
      pl.push(vA[i][1]);
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Play This" onClick="playThis(%s)" /></td></tr>',idx,vA[i][0],vA[i][1],idx++);
    }
  }
  html+='</table>';
  return {playlist:pl,html:html};
}
```

There are several default lists and id's that you will have to modify when you first set it up.  I wrote this for me not for other users with lesser experience. It's been working for more that six years. I use it to listen to my music every morning.  In fact I'm listening to it now as I write this.  I'm currently creating a random selection mode.

It's also a bit slow loading and the pause between songs is rather long.  But I'm not very picky about it.  If you are then you can modify the code yourself.

If you want to have a random playlist of your selected items then replay the getPlayList() with this one:

```
function getPlaylist() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('MusicList');
  var rg = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA = rg.getValues().filter(r => r[4] == true).sort((a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  var pl = [];
  var idx = 0;
  var html = '<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Index</th><th>Item</th><th>FileName</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>';
  vA.forEach(r => {
    pl.push(r[1]);
    html += Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="button" value="Play This" onClick="playThis(%s)" /></td></tr>', idx, r[0], r[1], idx++);
  });
  html += '</table>';
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="40" rows="12">${html}</textarea>`),"Dialog");
  return { playlist: pl, html: html };
}
```

> One very important requirement for this script is that every file in the music folder must have a unique name no exceptions.

Comment: Note I found an error in the html.  I found it with an online html Validator.  I fixed it in the code above.  It was in the playNext function

Comment: Okay this is working pretty good now.  I had some small issues but now it's increment to the next song automatically.