# Can appscript in Google Sheets invoke methods in an HTML5 Audio object?

Tags: google-apps-script, html5-audio

I have a sheet for a cover band that lists song titles, keys, links to YT videos, and beats-per-minute (BPM) in various columns.  Ideally, I'd like to play a metronomic beat when a user clicks on a cell with a specific BPM value (like loading an HREF but no page is loaded, just JS code).  It's fairly straightforward to create a metronome using HTML5 Audio and Javascript.  Is it possible to call HTML5 Javascript from an onClick() in a Sheets cell?  Or is it possible to dynamically create an HTML5 page/template in Sheets (Appscript) where I can pass the BPM of the user-selected cell?

Any advice is more than welcome.

I've tried HTMLService and thought I could send my entire JS code to it, but that does not work.  It doesn't seem to like page-length JS code.

Comment: You can certainly do it with a html dialog.

Comment: You can probably put your entire js code into a dialog and use - [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to communicate with your server functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218032/7215091

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946538/7215091

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I'll give that a try.